# Issue when building OPENCV in ARM Docker container

Tags: opencv, docker, go, dockerfile

I am facing an issue when building OPENCV in ARM Docker container :

```
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/opencv/opencv-3.4.2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/tmp/opencv/opencv-3.4.2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
The command '/bin/sh -c cd /tmp/opencv/opencv-3.4.2 &&     mkdir build &&     cd build &&     cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE           -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local           -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/tmp/opencv/opencv_contrib-3.4.2/modules           -D BUILD_DOCS=OFF           -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF           -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF           -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF           -D BUILD_opencv_java=OFF           -D BUILD_opencv_python=OFF           -D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF           -D BUILD_opencv_python3=OFF .. &&     make -j1 &&     make install &&     rm -rf /tmp/opencv' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Here is the Dockerfile that I use :

```
FROM armhf/ubuntu
LABEL maintainer="Xxxxx XXXX <xxxx.xxxx@xxxx.com>"

# Dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \ 
    apt-get upgrade -y && \ 
    apt-get install -y wget unzip build-essential cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libtbb2 libtbb-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libdc1394-22-dev

# Download OPENCV
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/opencv && \ 
    cd /tmp/opencv && \ 
    wget --show-progress --quiet -O opencv.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.4.2.zip && \ 
    unzip -o -q opencv.zip && \ 
    wget --show-progress --quiet -O opencv_contrib.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.4.2.zip && \ 
    unzip -o -q opencv_contrib.zip && \ 
    rm opencv.zip opencv_contrib.zip 

# Build OPENCV
RUN cd /tmp/opencv/opencv-3.4.2 && \ 
    mkdir build && \ 
    cd build && \ 
    cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
          -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \ 
          -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/tmp/opencv/opencv_contrib-3.4.2/modules \ 
          -D BUILD_DOCS=OFF \ 
          -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \ 
          -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF \ 
          -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF \ 
          -D BUILD_opencv_java=OFF \ 
          -D BUILD_opencv_python=OFF \ 
          -D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF \ 
          -D BUILD_opencv_python3=OFF .. && \ 
    make -j1 && \ 
    make install && \ 
    rm -rf /tmp/opencv

ADD go-coop-camera /usr/bin

WORKDIR /usr/bin

EXPOSE 8000
CMD [ "/usr/bin/go-coop-camera", "--logging", "info" ]
```

Do you see something that could be wrong ?
I tried to apply this fix : https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6027

But it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it was too obvious to see it, I was downloaded the same ZIP two times..

```
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.4.2.zip
```

instead of

```
https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/archive/3.4.2.zip
```